# No Suitable Driver JEE

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, mysql-connector, lib

i keep getting  " No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_catal".

I have put MySQL connector in the buildpath and also in lib folder of web-inf. Why am I still getting this error?
[Voici l'image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esTyL.png)

code :

```
package dao;
import java.sql.*;

public class SingletonConnection {

    private static Connection connection ;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_catal","root","");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   



          }
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection ;}    

    }
```

Comment: english please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your driver first before calling the `getConnection()` method.

if you have already done then you have to set classpath for `mysql-connectorXXXX.jar`

In eclipse, use the build path.

Your program like below will compile fine but as soon as you will run it you will get the error "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for `"jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_catal"` because of the JDBC URL format "`jdbc:mysql`" is not matching with any registered JDBC driver.

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/javasqlsqlexception-no-suitable-driver-mysql-jdbc-localhost.html#ixzz67da2aSqw

How to add jar to classPath through eclipse

- Right click on your project
- Select Build Path Click on Configure Build Path
- Click on Libraries and make sure mysql jar is present
- if not select the jar file from the required folder
- click on order and export tab. make sure you selected all
- Click and Apply and Ok

Comment: hello thanks for answering i tried that by adding the mysql connector to the libraries from project/buildpath/Libaries/add External jar 
 but it didnt work is that what you mean by classpath ?

Comment: @Flàyn I added instructions to add jar to eclipse.

Comment: thx . but it dosent work still the same Image : https://postimg.cc/sMhP2jq5

Comment: @Flàyn Can you try this and see if e1 is printing out ```try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}```

Comment: i tried it image : https://postimg.cc/gxH1kLj6 

i dont think e1 is printing out

Comment: replace line 9 with the try catch i shared you.

Comment: i tired it and there is no e1 exception i think here is the image : https://postimg.cc/SXF3YqC0